# Background services on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, daemon, launchd, background-service, launch-daemon

I want to make an OS X app which continuously capture photo in some time interval and send that photo to the server via any service (HTTP/Socket).

I searched about this and get that to achieve the same I need to make a daemon service (using launchd) for mac which will run on background.

But I am still confused with the procedure.

For example, I have created a plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.lc1</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Documents/LD/FirstScript.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Documents/LD/Error_log.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Documents/LD/Output_log.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I copied plist file to ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Then use the command

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.lc1.plist
```

But I am not getting any output now.

For the photo capture, I am using imagesnap ([Referred](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/)):

```
./imagesnap
```

How can I achieve photo capture and service (HTTP/Socket) implementation in background?

How I can send photo to the server in background?

Need help.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far, that's the only way to help...

Comment: @l'L'l : Sure. I've modified my question. Please check.

Comment: You need to put another key in the .plist `<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>`

Comment: @l'L'l : Thanks. Done that too but still not getting any log in logfile. For example, I am just using echo hello world in my "FirstScript.sh" file.

Comment: You'll also need to use `launchctl start com.me.lc1` to run it after loading.

Comment: @l'L'l: Thanks, that worked. But is there any way to capture photo and call a service via the same process?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, there probably is a way, but you'll have to try it first I'd imagine (eg. adding the `./imagesnap` command to the `.sh` script). I'm not sure what you mean by "call a service" either.

Comment: @l'L'l : From "Call a service", I mean I need to send this captured image data to server (via socket or via web service calling).

Comment: I am facing same issues .Could please help to solved the issue .. Instead of FirstScript.sh i need to call application .app file